# Would changing local OS time affect the database?

Tags: linux, oracle, oracle11g

Currently our stand-alone 11g R2 Oracle database has the wrong time as the local OS server (Linux redhat) also has the wrong time (off by several minutes).

Can I just ask a sysadmin to change the OS time by several minutes; does that affect the database? Does the database need to be restarted after the local OS time changed has been changed? Does database need to be down while doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the operating system time won't impact the Oracle database itself and doesn't require any downtime.

Changing the operating system time may, however, impact the applications that are running in the Oracle database.  You would need to talk with the owner(s) of those application(s) to determine whether there would actually be an impact.  If, for example, an application depends on some `DATE` column indicating the order in which rows are inserted and/or modified, moving the clock back by a few minutes may cause data issues for the application where a row was modified before it was inserted or the last update isn't actually the last update.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is probably to get an outage window, shut down Oracle, set up NTP, then restart Oracle.